# Help with matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose T is a symmetric orthogonal matrix of degree $4n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$. Write $v=(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$, where each $v_i \in \mathbb Z^n$ and so $v \in \mathbb Z^{4n}$. Similarly, write $u=(u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4)$, where each $u_i \in \mathbb Z^n$ and so $u \in \mathbb Z^{4n}$. Suppose that $v=uT$. Then why is
$\sum_{i=1}^4 v_i^T v_i = \sum_{i=1}^4 u_i^T u_i$?

Clarification about notation: the vectors $v$ and $u$ are row vectors and so $v_i^Tv_i$ is a matrix of degree $n$.

Comment: Are $v_i$'s column vectors or row vectors? The expression $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\in\mathbb Z^{4n}$ implies that $v_i$'s are row vectors, but $\sum v_i^{\mathrm T}v_i$ implies that they're column vectors.

Comment: Also, please add contexts as per [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).

Comment: They are row vectors. Hence, as mentioned in the question, $\sum v_{i}^T v_i$ is an $n \times n$ matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I would like to present a hint for the problem.
In my answer I will assume that $n=1$, and I will work with standard notation, namely using column vectors

$$
x = u^\mathsf{T}, y = v^\mathsf{T}.
$$

Please note that orthogonal condition for the matrix leads to the following equation

$$
T^\mathsf T T = T T^\mathsf T = 1,
$$

which is equivalent to the following

$$
\sum_k T_{ik} T_{kj}^\mathsf T = \sum_k T_{ik} ^\mathsf T T_{kj} = \delta_{ij},
$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Note that from the assumptions we have $T x = y$, which corresponds to
the equation

$$
 \sum_j T_{ij} x_j = y_i.
$$

Then applying this to the problem statement one can get

$$
\sum_i y_i y_i^\mathsf T 
= \sum_i \left(\sum_j T_{ij} x_j \right) \left(\sum_k  x_k^\mathsf T T_{ik}^\mathsf T \right) = 
\sum_{ijk} x_j x_k^\mathsf T T_{ij} T_{ik}^\mathsf T
$$

Then using that matrix $T$ is symmetric ($T_{ij} = T_{ji}$)

$$
\sum_i y_i y_i^\mathsf T = \sum_{jk} x_j x_k^\mathsf T \underbrace{\sum_i T_{ji} T_{ik}^\mathsf T}_{\delta_{jk}} = \sum_{jk} x_j x_k^\mathsf T \delta_{jk}.
$$

Finally, using delta property $ \sum_i x_i \delta_{ij} = x_j$

$$
\boxed{\sum_i y_i y_i^\mathsf T = \sum_{i} x_i x_i^\mathsf T }
$$